# Kotlin - Two Way Data Binding with 2 EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried out android's two way data binding in kotlin but I can't seem to get it working. I have 2 EditText and each of them should update the other EditText.

For example:
When i enter "Test" in EditText1 the EditText2 should get updated with the value from EditText1 plus a suffix `(e.g. TestSUFFIX)` and vice versa.

These are the layouts for my `TextViews`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={convertermodel.valueFrom}" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={convertermodel.valueTo}" />
```

and this is my `ViewModel`

```
class ConverterModel : BaseObservable() {

   @Bindable
   var valueFrom: String? = null
       get() {
           return valueTo + "SUFFIX"
       }
       set(param) {
           field = param
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.valueFrom)
       }

   @Bindable
   var valueTo: String? = null
       get() {
           return valueFrom + "SUFFIX"
       }
       set(param) {
           field = param
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.valueTo)
       }
}
```

It's causing an infinite loop. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to data biding at all. Your implementation causes recursive calls to your getters:
valueFrom.get() will call valueTo.get() and it will call again valueFrom.get() -> StackOverflowError.

You have to use kotlin backing properties, for example:

```
class AccessTest {

    var _valueTo: String? = null
    var _valueFrom: String? = null

    var valueFrom: String? = null
        get() {
            return _valueTo + "SUFFIX"
        }
        set(param) {
            field = param
            _valueFrom = param
        }

    var valueTo: String? = null
        get() {
            return _valueFrom + "SUFFIX"
        }
        set(param) {
            field = param
            _valueTo = param
        }

    @Test
    fun testAccess() {
        valueTo= "valueTo"
        valueFrom= "valueFrom"
        print(valueTo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the setter's value if it's same value, then do not set it again:

```
class ConverterModel : BaseObservable() {

    @Bindable
   var valueFrom: String? = null
       get() {
           return valueTo + "SUFFIX"
       }
       set(param) {
           if (field == param) return
           field = param
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.valueFrom)
       }

   @Bindable
   var valueTo: String? = null
       get() {
           return valueFrom + "SUFFIX"
       }
       set(param) {
           if (field == param) return
           field = param
           notifyPropertyChanged(BR.valueTo)
       }
}
```